# Plagiarism detection software/website for academic thesis/papers

Tags: windows, plagiarism-detection

I have written a thesis for my academic career at post-graduate level. I want to check whether I have unintentionally plagiarized some stuff from the published papers or other academic websites.

I need a free software that checks for plagiarized contents in documents. Registration for account is of no problem. I need it for Windows operating system.

**Edit: Some background information**

I am an M Tech student. I have completed my final year project in DSP Engineering domain & written a thesis on it as well.
When I started working on the project a year back, the 1st step was getting to know what the specific area of the project was about. So I read many papers, other theses and of course academic websites and forums. I have a habit of writing down important points when I come across.
There were quarterly reports that I wrote and submitted about the project. I did not cite any part of those reports as they were for internal use for my guide for staying up to date.
While writing the thesis, especially the initial chapters introducing the general working area of the project & specific information 
with relevant mathematical formulas & graphs & block diagrams etc, I referred to these quarterly reports. The rest of the thesis which is
the work done by me is not plagiarized as I wrote every word of it myself about what I did. So that's done.

Some of the papers/websites which I constantly visited were very easy for me to cite. But there are many papers/websites which I read to at the start and forgot about it.
There is a possibility, that I have used certain excerpts from a paper/website but I don't know which, so I can't cite them.
Some of you said, mild plagiarism doesn't matter in Engineering field. But plagiarism, mild or not, matters to me.
I have not even plagiarized a tweet so far.
It's just for personal satisfaction.

Comment: How can you 'unknowingly plagiarize'? And did you google 'check plagiarism'? That immediately gives results. I can't recommend any of these because I don't know them but testing some of them would help you (us) with a more specific question. All SE sites like questioners to have done a little homework before asking a question.

Comment: Unintentional would be a good word. I tried searching in Google. I tried some websites but even after registration they ask u to pay money

Comment: In what field of science do you work? I think that probably a fear of "unintentional plagiarism" can be related only to humanities. In any case, the word "plagiarism" implies that a person does it intentionally.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov in the field of DSP Engineering.

Comment: If you work on digital signal processing, it is surprising that you have a fear of "unintentional plagiarism" because (as I understand) even if you re-discover some known method, such re-discovering cannot be considered as plagiarism even if this method is patented. Probably you just misunderstand the word "plagiarism".

Comment: Taking a valuable excerpt from someone's work without citing them is called plagiarism. The field should not matter. If u know of a s/w then please answer. The debate over what plagiarism is is not for this site no?

Comment: I think that what the others suggest is that you shouldn't be afraid of incurring in **plagiarism** if you are completely sure you didn't take an *excerpt from someone's work without citing them*, but if you did, cite them or delete that excerpt from your theses..

Comment: I will try & rephrase the question @arielnmz.

Comment: This does not seem to be primarily a software problem. What you need is a _service_ that has access to a data set appropriate for this task. While some web-apps would be on topic here as they are used like software and we can compare them on features and suitability for a task, what you really need is a service provider that has data to compare to and the tools to access their data. That is somewhat outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @Caleb if u search for plagiarism checker software in Google, many downloadable softwares turn up & many more online checkers turn up. But I've tried a few but they require payment & all. So I asked a question here if anybody had an experience of using a good free software. I dont know what you are suggesting

Comment: It's not the software that is a problem here, it is the access to databases of existing research to compare against. You aren't looking for free software you are looking for free programmatic access to published material that would normally be behind paywalls. Good luck with that. It's just not a software question.

Comment: @Caleb regarding access to published material re:IEEE Explore, I have full access through my University ISP. So yeah, free softwares might not have access to IEEE published content but most of the IEEE papers are available for free albeit pirated versions of it. Some one might have got a workaround s/w. Anyway, I'll wait

Comment: Now I understand your problem. I can suggest at least one possible way which you can use in the case if you will not get easier solution. You can take key parts of sentences/paragraphs from your thesis and Google for them. If the sentence is a plagiarism you will see it on the very top of the search results. Of course, this method can be programmatically automatized to some extent.

Comment: Avoid free plagiarism detection tools at all costs. The thing is that such online resources duplicate content to their own database. As an educator, you need to care about privacy issues. I recommend you to use Unplag [plagiarism checker](https://unplag.com/) because it uses live-web indexes, moreover this plagiarism detection engine can identify letters from other alphabet and recognize incorrect citations (and you know that this is more than stylistic error.

Comment: https://github.com/architshukla/Plagiarism-Checker

Answer (score 1):

writecheck.com offers a service for students, but it costs per paper.  Then again, $10 doesn't seem like much when it is your final work...  it is created by turnitin, which a LOT of institutions use for checking student work.  http://en.writecheck.com/

HOWEVER... I have moral issues with using turnitin since their business model depends on forcing students to relinquish IP rights in order to receive a grade.  Should you decide to use writecheck, check the ToS carefully to ensure that they aren't laying claim to your paper, etc.

Comment: I had a prof that forced us to use turnitin even to staunch objections.  I don't understand how such a service is legal.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the services which you can try:

- [Copyscape](http://www.copyscape.com/) (premium),
- [PlagSpotter](http://www.plagspotter.com/) (premium),
- [Copyleaks](https://copyleaks.com/) (premium, [API](https://api.copyleaks.com/))

Free APIs:

- [Yahoo Boss](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/) (useful for manual searching or automating from the script)

Source: [Copyright content API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4226162/55075) at StackOverflow