# Free plagiarism detection tool for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, plagiarism-detection

I'm looking for a free software that will be able to scan through my paper and detect for each written sentence its paper source (by using the web). This will help me to detect if I used a sentence from other paper and forgot to add its citation.

The software should go through every sentence in the paper and look for it in papers in the web. The OS is Windows 7 and on. The software should be freeware. Something similar to [SafeAssign](http://www.safeassign.com/).

Comment: Related: [Plagiarism detection software/website for acedemic thesis/papers](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/6870/60)

Comment: Thanks @unor, I would like to emphasize that I would like to find a safe software that doesn't index your paper or does any other manipulation with your paper.